# Why json_decode is not working?

Tags: php, arrays, json, file

I am trying read and json_decode a file which has some json_encoded elements. My php file is reading the encoded elements but not decoding it into an array. What is the problem?

```
<?php 
$filename1 ="history.txt";
$filecontent=file_get_contents($filename1);
$history=Array();
$history=json_decode($fileContent,true);
$ar_size=sizeof($history);
echo $filecontent;
echo $ar_size;
?>
```

The first echo is giving the file contents of file1, but the second echo is giving 0. My `history.txt` contains:

> ["  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11  &2.829476 ","  1 2 4 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
>   &2.782541 "]

Comment: ok, edited.. Still not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo.

```
$history=json_decode($fileContent,true);
$history=json_decode($filecontent,true);
```

Comment: no problem. a good IDE is telling you this type of errors. and php does, too: Notice: Undefined variable: fileContent in C:\...\....php on line 13